# How can I affect the transparency of many sprites at once through the parent GameObject?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a player that can move around a randomly generated map of rooms. I've been trying to figure out a way to keep all the rooms fully transparent/invisible, and then as soon as the player enters the room, that room becomes opaque.

I already have a way to detect the room the player is in, the main issue I'm having is changing the transparency of the room. Each room is made up of 30 or so "wall" tiles, which are just default square 2D sprites for now. These are the only thing I need to change the visibility of for now.

I saw that I can change the "material render value" or something similar to that per sprite, but I'm not sure of an easy way to do that for a whole lot of sprites at once that only have the default sprite renderer component and not a custom material.

Do I need to completely overhaul my rooms' walls to be one prefab for the whole wall? Or is there some way I could easily loop through each wall in a targeted room and change the transparency/visibility?

Comment: I would use a [transparency shader](https://forum.unity.com/threads/transparency-with-standard-surface-shader.394551/) and change the material when a room is discovered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `GameObject.SetActive(bool)` it has the utility to disable and enable the visibility of the GameObject.

(I believe you have already done this, but if not) In your hierarchy you would first create an Empty and add your room to it, rename it with the name of your room and you could use the following script when detecting the room the player is in.

```cs
public GameObject room; //link your room here

void Start()
{
    room.SetActive(false);
}

void Update()
{
    //When detecting the room
    room.SetActive(true);
}
```

The bool parameter of the SetActive() void sets whether the object is visible or not, when false it is invisible, and when true it is visible. I don't have your script as a reference, so I used an example

Answer (score 0):

You should use GetChild() and for {}. Get child gets the child of the index you chose, and accesses it. Here is the script:

```
void Update()
{
    for (int i = 0, i <= transform.childCount, i += 1)
    {
        GameObject child = GetChild(i);
        // change the values here using child.GetComponent<>()
    }
}
```

This is what the computer does: sets int i. Does this object have less children than the variable, i? Yes, run the code underneath. set child to the child of index i. i increases by 1. Repeat until i is greater than the child count.

Links:

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.GetChild.html
https://www.w3schools.com/cs/cs_for_loop.asp